# getting all the records in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i wanted to retrieve all the records whose "amount" is greater than or equal to 1500. The problem is even if the "amount" is less than 1500 it will be also displayed in the page.

```
customers table
id   name
1    sample
2    sample2
3    sample3


payments table

p_id  amount  id(foreign key)
1      800     2
2      800     2
3      1500    1
4      1200    3
```

costumer 1 and 2 should be retrieved because the amount>= 1500.

Thank you,
Mick :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: return all customers whose amount >= 1500

Comment: @Mick Austre - Each individual payment >= 1500 or total for a customer >= 1500?

Answer (score 3):

This requires to join the tables. `GROUP BY` is used since one of the columns is being aggregated using `SUM()` and the `HAVING` clause is used to filter the result of aggregation.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.name
FROM    customers a
        INNER JOIN payments b
            ON a.ID = b.id
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.name
HAVING  SUM(b.amount) >= 1500
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a664b/3)